# I am not able to download image dataset using tf.keras.util.get_file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am not able to download an image dataset using `tf.keras.util.get_file`

```
import pathlib
dataset_url = "https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahalide/plantvillage-dataset/download"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('PlantVillage Dataset',origin=dataset_url, untar=True)  
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
```

The output I got is

```
Downloading data from https://www.kaggle.com/abdallahalidev /plantvillage-dataset/download  
   8192/Unknown - 0s 2us/step
```

Why is this Unknown here?

Comment: Could you please make it a little cleaner? What is the Error you get? AND kaggle does not work in some countries, what country are you living in?

Comment: here the problem is the code is not able to download kaggle dataset behalf of showing file size it displays "Unknown". This leds to 0 image download. I am from India.